# How to solve xampp installation error on windows

Tags: mysql, apache

Error message is shown when 'Start' button is pressed on xampp's control panel for Apache and Mysql.

Comment: Please provide more information like what you did and what is the error message and did you google it up...

Comment: what is the error message you got it ?

Comment: @yossico thank you for offering help but I got the answer and thus posted it!

Comment: @kvmahesh Thanks ......got the answer !

Answer (score 1):

Steps :
Go to xampp control panel
Besides Apache and Mysql there is Config button

Click config button of Apache and in the text file which will open, search for "Listen port 80" and change it to "Listen port any number for eg. 1213"

Click config button of Mysql and in the text file which will open, search for "Listen port 443" and change it to "Listen port any number for eg. 1133"

Save Changes made above and then click start buttons of Apache and Mysql !
This time it should work!!! Also, uninstall Skype, if required.

The problem was caused because some other webserver was listening on ports 80 and 443 or because port 80 and port 443 are privileged ports and the user running xampp has no right to claim these ports for listening.

Comment: welcome and thanks for sharing your knowledge on stackoverflow.com.